# Callback on posting to G+ user stream

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

When the user shares a link on their G+ stream through my Android app, how do I detect if the post was successful?

This is what I'm doing to post a link.

```
PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(ExampleActivity.this)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://example.com"))
    .setText("Check out this website");
Intent shareIntent = builder.getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, GPLUS_SHARE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I overrode `onActivityResult` to check the `resultCode`. It does return `RESULT_OK` if it is successful, but is it possible to get more elaborate information, like the post submission failing due to a network error etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a callback function for a Share action.  However, there is a known feature request for one in the G+ Platform Issue Tracker.  If you Star the issue, you will receive email updates on it.

For Shares: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=232
For Interactive Posts specifically: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=521

For now, the RESULT_OK check is a decent solution.